# How do I retrieve the file name (s) from the server in client-server application?

Tags: java, sockets, file-io, io, client-server

I have been working with a client-server application where the client should be able to get the list of file (the name of the files). The client types corresponding command to the server and the server gives back the files name stored in it's directory.

However, I am able to print out the file names, but not all the files. Right now the program prints only one file (the first one). In reality, in the server directory, I have several files. *How can I get all the files?*

Here, I am going to copy-paste only the part of code responsible for getting the file:

Server class:

```
            //receive getList command from the client
            String commandGetList = inputFromClient.readUTF();

            String path = ".";

            String files;
            File folder = new File(path);
            File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

            for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {

                if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                    files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
                    outputToClient.writeUTF(files);
                }

            }
```

Area side:

```
//enter the command to get the list of files
            System.out.println("Enter getList command: ");
            String commandGetList = sc.nextLine();//store that command
            //sending that command to the server
            outputToServer.writeUTF(commandGetList);
            outputToServer.flush();//flushing out the stream

            //getting the listed file from the server
            String listedFileFromSErver = inputFromServer.readUTF();

            System.out.println("You have the following files in the server directory: " + listedFileFromSErver);
```

Comment: Where is the client code?

Comment: The first thing is to find out, if the problem is on the server or the client side. So start your server in debug mode and look, if the server finds all the expected files and sends them correctly to the client. If yes, then debug your client.

Comment: Martin James, I have added the client code